# how to resolve return argument implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, remix

```
 function getFrom(bytes32 transferId)public returns (address ) {
    Transfer memory transfer = transfers[transferId];        
    if (msg.sender != transfer.to && msg.sender != transfer.from)  return 0x0;
    return transfer.from;
}
function getTo(bytes32 transferId)public returns (address) {
    Transfer memory transfer = transfers[transferId];
 if (msg.sender != transfer .to && msg.sender != transfer .from) return 0x0;
    return transfer.to;
}
```

I am getting error like this

```
TypeError: Return argument type int_const 0 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) address. if (msg.sender != transfer.to && msg.sender != transfer.from) return 0x0; ^-^
```

how to resolve this issue?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit type conversion:

```
        return address(0x00);
```